# How to make Groovy / Grails return a List of objects instead of a List of Lists of objects?

Tags: grails, collections, groovy, closures, collect

I have a class like this:

```
class Foo {
    static hasMany = [bars: Bar]
}
```

When I write:

```
Foo.getAll()
```

I get a list of `Foo` objects like this:

```
[ Foo1, Foo2, Foo3 ]
```

When I write:

```
Foo.getAll().bars
```

I get a list of lists of `Bar` object like this:

```
[ [ Bar1, Bar2 ], [ Bar2, Bar3 ], [ Bar1, Bar4 ] ]
```

But what I want is a unique list of `Bar` objects like this:

```
[ Bar1, Bar2, Bar3, Bar4 ]
```

My end goal is to have a unique list of ids of the `Bar` object in the list above, like this:

```
[ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
```

I have tried variations of the [collect](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#collect%28groovy.lang.Closure%29) method and I have also tried the [spread operator](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Operators#Operators-SpreadOperator) but I'm not having any luck.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For generic groovy classes (i.e. non-GORM classes), David is correct that using `flatten` and `unique` is the best way to go.

In your example though, it looks like you're using GORM domain objects in a many-to-many relationship (otherwise you wouldn't need the uniqueness constraint).

For a domain class, you're best off using either HQL or a criteria to do this in one step.  An additional advantage is that the SQL generated for it is much more efficient.

Here's the HQL for getting the unique `Bar` ids that are related to any `Foo` in a many-to-many relationship:

```
Bar.executeQuery("select distinct b.id from Foo f join f.bars b")
```

The criteria for this would look like:

```
Foo.withCriteria {
    bars {
        projections {
          distinct("id")
        }
    }
}
```

One "issue" with using this kind of method is that HQL is not supported in unit tests (and likely will never be) and [Criteria queries with join table projections are broken in 2.0.4 unit tests](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-9161).  So any tests around this code would either need to be mocked or use an integration test.

Comment: Thanks for all your answers guys. Wish I could upvote you all more :)  I wanted to avoid HQL, but having almost completed my quest using criteria, I now find pagination to be... troublesome. If I cannot get pagination to play nice using criteria I will have to go to HQL I think.

Answer (score 4):

There might be a better way, but you could use [flatten](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#flatten%28%29) and [unique](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#unique%28%29).

Something like:

`def allBars = Foo.getAll().bars.flatten().unique()`

Edit:
I've just re-read and see that you are after a list of IDs in the end, not the Bars. As you suggested you would use `collect{ it.id }` to get the IDs. I would do that before making the list unique, for performance reasons.

Answer (score 4):

There is a [`Collection#collectMany`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#collectMany%28groovy.lang.Closure%29) method that works the same way as calling `collect` and then `flatten`. To get the list of Bar IDs, you might do:

```
def barIds = Foo.getAll().collectMany { it.bars*.id }
```

The `{ it.bars*.id }` closure returns a list with the IDs of the Bars of a Foo (i love these placeholder names hehe), and then `collectMany` concatenates those lists into a single list. If you need the IDs to be unique (maybe a Bar can belong to more than one Foo), you can add a [`.unique()`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#unique%28%29) to that expression :)